# Does this schema design support efficient querying in Realm?

Tags: database, realm, schema

If I had a series of `Row`s in a Realm database, each one containing a field that was a List `[Points]` of thousands of coordinate objects (`p1`, `p2`, ...`pn`) - and each one of those coordinates had a field for a `TAG` property which may not exist - would there be an efficient and inexpensive way to query for results such as the following based on `TAG` value (i.e. `p3` below)

1. individual `Row`s (where `[Points]` contains point(s) that has `TAG` property matching a queried value)
2. an array of objects each containing a new `[Points]` list with `Point`s from hundreds of `Row`s and a reference to which `Row` they came from (there could be several `Row`s with an array of `[Points]`, certain elements of which contain the `TAG` property that match the value queried for. I want those points extracted from all of the `Row`s)

---

- Row
- Row
- Row

  - [Points]

    - p1

      - lat
      - lon
    - p2

      - lat
      - lon
    - p3

      - lat
      - lon
      - TAG
    - p4
    - ...

---

[This article](https://academy.realm.io/posts/threading-deep-dive/) says:

> Relationships in Realm are also extremely fast because they’re indexes that traverse a B‑tree–like structure to the related object. This is much faster than querying. Because of this there is no need to perform another full query as ORMs do. It simply is a native pointer to the related object.

But my concern is the size of the dataset: A query of type 2 above would involve going through hundreds of `Row`s each containing thousands of `Point`s and checking each one of those points to see a) if the `TAG` property is present and b) if it's value matches the query.

I want to be able to specify a TAG value, then find all instances of Rows as well as coordinates containing that TAG value within a date range. This would happen locally on device, as well as on a server hosting the Realm Object Server. A request like this could happen over the network as well.

Comment: Please let me know if I can clarify. I'll try to monitor as best I can

Comment: This doesn't seem like too big of a deal however question 2 a bit vague. To clarify 1) are you asking if you can query the [points] object for all points that have a TAG?

Comment: @Jay thanks for taking a look. I've edited the question. For case 1) (the more trivial one I hope) detecting a point within the Row's [Points] list that has TAG equal to a value, and then just pulling the whole Row.